# Make CSS DIV blocks responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this code which allows me to placed various content into the fixed-placed CSS-defined div blocks which works marvellously - BUT sometimes I would need such page to be responsive - do you think it can be done?
I have included the code:

```css
#page_content  {
   min-height: 2000px;
}
    
#rectangle1  {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* [disabled]background-image: url(sg_prototype_media/rectangle1.gif); */
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    height: 153px;
    width: 479px;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 48px;
    left: 29px;
    position: absolute;
}

#rectangle2  {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* [disabled]background-image: url(sg_prototype_media/rectangle2.gif); */
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    height: 153px;
    width: 856px;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 48px;
    left: 524px;
    position: absolute;
}

#rectangle3  {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* [disabled]background-image: url(sg_prototype_media/rectangle3.gif); */
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    height: 884px;
    width: 520px;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 48px;
    left: 1403px;
    position: absolute;
}

#rectangle4  {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* [disabled]background-image: url(sg_prototype_media/rectangle3.gif); */
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    height: 701px;
    width: 1351px;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 229px;
    left: 29px;
    position: absolute;
}

#background  {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* [disabled]background-image: url(sg_prototype_media/background.gif); */
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    height: 2000px;
    width: 2000px;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}

.page_content_bkg  {
   width: 2000px;
   height: 2000px;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   display: block;
}

.container_div  {
   position: relative;
   width: 2000px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-left: auto;
}

.spacing_div  {
   min-height: 0px;
   height: 0px;
}

*:focus  {
   outline-style: none;
}

.full_width  {
   position: relative;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   min-width: 2000px;
}

ains  {
   text-decoration: none;
}

html, body  {
   height: 100%;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

body  {
   -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
   height: 100%;
   padding-bottom: 0px;
   padding-top: 0px;
   padding-right: 0px;
   padding-left: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<!-- (sg_cms) -->
<!--  -->
<!-- (sg_emit "sg_prototype_content/title.xml") -->
</head>
<body>
 <div id="page_div">
  <div class="full_width" id="page_content">
   <div class="container_div">
  <div id="background" class=""></div>
  <div id="rectangle1" class="">
    <iframe src="https://www.ubs.com/global/en.html"height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="rectangle2" class=""><iframe src="https://www.ubs.com/global/en.html"height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </iframe></div>
  <div id="rectangle3" class=""><iframe src="https://www.ubs.com/global/en.html"height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </iframe></div>
  <div id="rectangle4" class=""><iframe src="https://www.ubs.com/global/en.html"height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </iframe></div>
  
    <div id="pagesize_gap" style="height:2000px;"></div>
    <div id="clear_footer"></div>
   </div><!-- /prototype container_div -->
  </div><!-- /page_content:full_width -->
 </div><!-- /page_div -->

<!-- (sg_chau) -->
<!-- (sg_suppress  -->  <!--) -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*do you think it can be done?*" -- Yes. You will have to do a lot of changes in your markup and styling. Start by drawing on paper how do you want your website to look like in different screen sizes. Once done that, read up tutorials on responsive design. Try doing things one by one. Check out libraries like Bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you for your reply...I was hoping there is a fast way to do this by adding some some plug-in or code) Can it not be just made responsive by treating each block as for example gallery picture and using responsive gallery script?

Comment: :) There are no shortcuts in life @gabriel. But, you may want to spend time reading up the Bootstrap docs to learn how it can help you do that with minimal effort. Do not expect it go easier than that though.

Answer (score 2):

Use css media queries to change the screen sizes of particular target.
It will matches the screen it will stretches..

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #rectangle1  {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* [disabled]background-image: url(sg_prototype_media/rectangle1.gif); */
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    height: inherit;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 20%;
    left: 10%;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

By this way you can achieve a responsive stretchable layouts.. Use every pixels as to converted percentage..

For nice results you can use Bootstrap css..